# É possível coletar um código fonte html usando python?

Tags: html, python, python-2.7

Eu gostaria de algo em python, alguma biblioteca que conseguisse acessar o site e pegar o código fonte dela (HTML). Exemplo:

```
Talsite.com
<h1>hello</h1>
```

É possível que façam python entrar em Talsite.com e coletar o código fonte dele? Se sim, como?

Estou usando o python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Python 2:

```
import urllib
url = "https://pt.stackoverflow.com"
f = urllib.urlopen(url)
print f.read()
```

#### Python 3:

```
import urllib.request
url = "https://pt.stackoverflow.com"
f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
print(f.read())
```